# discord.py @bot.command() not working in the channels but DM OK

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, bots

I wrote a bot using discord.py. The problem is it responds to my DM, but not to my message in channels. Could anyone help with it?

```
import discord
import requests
import urllib.request
import os
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image 
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
@bot.event 
async def on_ready(): 
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))

@bot.event 
async def on_message(message): 
    await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.command() 
async def bothello(ctx): 
    print(ctx.channel) 
    if isinstance(ctx.channel, discord.DMChannel): 
        await ctx.send(f'DM') 
    elif isinstance(ctx.channel, discord.TextChannel): 
        print(ctx.channel.name) 
        await ctx.send(f'channel: {ctx.channel.name}') 
    else: 
        print("no way") 
    print('hello')

bot.run('MY_BOT_TOKEN')
```

I tried to modify the permisson but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will guess that you're using `discord.py` library and not its forks, since it's in your question tags.

So, first, it doesn't look like you're using `discord.py 2.0` since you're not getting an exception about not passing the `intents` keyword argument. Make sure that you have an up-to-date `discord.py` by trying to update it using: `python -m pip install -U discord.py`

Second, the reason your bot isn't responding to commands in the server is because you don't have the [message_content](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message_content#discord.Intents.message_content) privileged intent that was new in 2.0; since it doesn't have the intent, it cannot access the content of the message that was sent in the server, so you need to enable it in the dev portal and in the code. Example (code):

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(..., intents=intents)
```

You may want to look at `discord.py`'s guide on how to enable the intent in the dev portal [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html#privileged-intents).

Comment: Hi there. Thanks a lot for the help! But after upgrading and adding the codes you gave and setting the option via the dev portal, the issue is still there. Any more suggestions?  Appreciate it!

Comment: @BryanZheng How is the code look like now?

Comment: I figured out how stupid I was... Always at the bot in the channel. It was totally unnecessary!  Now everything is peachy! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Catgal This was very helpful. I looked at several code samples, but this your solution resolved my issue!